# Extension shows up in the extensions page but not in the user data directory

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am creating a chrome extension. It is showing up in the `chrome://extensions/` page but not in the [user data dir](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md)`/Default/Extensions` directory. All the other extensions (installed from the app store) are showing.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, only packed extensions show up in the `{user data dir}/Default/Extensions`.

First pack the extension, by clicking on `Pack extension` on the `chrome://extensions` page.

Then load that extension, by clicking on `Load extension`.

Now the packed (not the other unpacked one) will show up in `{user data dir}/Default/Extensions`.